# While using TestNG if we define WebDriver driver; globally then without creating object of that class how we are able to use driver under a method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

The code is working fine but why? without creating object of class `Testing123` How we are able to access that driver?

```
public class Testing123 {
    WebDriver driver ;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TestNG framework is taking care of creating an instance of your test class behind the scenes. Basically by annotating your method with '@Test' the annotation processor associate the class to the test runner. For further info look at: http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2018/06/08/testng-tutorials-21-why-dont-we-require-a-main-method-in-testng-class-for-execution-of-methods/